# Python animation, line starting from moving point and stopping at second intersection

Tags: python, matplotlib, simulation

I'm making a program to simulate the retrograde motion of mars visible from Earth.
So it's a plan view of Earth and Mars orbiting the sun
There is also a line going from Earth to Mars.
However, I need it to intersect the point that is Mars and keep going until it intersects the line x = 15

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def _update_plot(i, fig, scat, l):
        scat.set_offsets(([math.cos(math.radians(i))*5, math.sin(math.radians(i))*5], [math.cos(math.radians(i/2))*10, math.sin(math.radians(i/2))*10], [0, 0]))
        l.set_data(([math.cos(math.radians(i))*5,math.cos(math.radians(i/2))*10],[math.sin(math.radians(i))*5,math.sin(math.radians(i/2))*10]))
        return [scat,l]

fig = plt.figure()

x = [0]
y = [0]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.grid(True, linestyle = '-', color = '0.10')
ax.set_xlim([-11, 11])
ax.set_ylim([-11, 11])

l, = plt.plot([],[], 'r--', zorder=1)
scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c = x, zorder=2)
scat.set_alpha(0.8)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs = (fig, scat, l),
                               frames = 720, interval = 10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but I'll assume you want to extend the line that connects the two planets up to x = 15. In this case you can do the following:

- Compute the Earth-Mars direction by subtracting their position and normalising the resulting vector. Take one of the planet as the starting point of the line.
- Solve the first-order equation that gives you the distance you need to travel to get to the x = 15 axis.
- Check whether the result is positive or negative. If it's positive then keep going, if it's negative we chose the wrong planet, as in order for the line to connect the two planes and then keep going towards x = 15 we need to take the other planet. We do so by inverting the direction and re-solving the first-order equation with the new conditions.
- Find the y-coordinate of the point at which the line intersects the x = 15 axis
- Draw a line from the planet to the intersection point on the x = 15 axis.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
def _update_plot(i, fig, scat, l):
        angle = math.radians(i)

        sun_pos = np.array([0., 0.])
        earth_pos = np.array([math.cos(angle)*5, math.sin(angle)*5])
        mars_pos = np.array([math.cos(angle / 2.) * 10, math.sin(angle / 2.) * 10])

        # compute the unit vector that points from Earth to Mars
        direction = mars_pos - earth_pos
        direction /= np.sqrt(np.dot(direction, direction))

        # find out where the line would intersect the x = 15 axis
        start_from = earth_pos
        alpha = (15 - start_from[0]) / direction[0]
        # if alpha comes out to be negative we picked the "wrong" planet
        if alpha < 0:
                start_from = mars_pos
                direction = -direction
                alpha = (15 - start_from[0]) / direction[0]
        y_line = start_from[1] + alpha * direction[1]

        # draw the planets
        scat.set_offsets((earth_pos, mars_pos, sun_pos))
        # draw the line
        l.set_data(([start_from[0], 15], [start_from[1], y_line]))
        return [scat,l]
```